# Android pushNotificationReceived event not firing when app is in foreground

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm using the push plugin with ngCordova, and I'm not getting any pushNotificationReceived events firing when the Android app is in the foreground. The event fires when I do a device registration and it also seems to work for iOS - it's only on Android when the app is in foreground.

When the app is in the background, I get the standard push notification banners with no problem, but clicking through the banner doesn't trigger the pushNotificationReceived either.

```
angular.module('my.controllers', [])

  .controller('AppCtrl',function ($scope, $ionicModal, $state, $q, UserService, $cordovaPush) {
    $scope.$on('pushNotificationReceived', function (event, notification) {

      //this never gets called on Android if the message 
      //comes in the background through a notification 
      //this does however get triggered by the push registration event.
      alert('notification '+ JSON.stringify(notification));
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using [PushPlugin](http://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)?